# How to return date formatted as 'month, year'

Tags: python, python-3.9

```
def format_date_joined(date):
    return
```

So the function is supposed to take in a date as an argument then return it with the month, year format. I'm not sure exactly how to do that as I don't even know what format the date would be entered.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
If you don't yet know the input format, then you don't have any way to specify your problem.  You need to solve that.

Comment: Also, you haven't finished your research on converting date formats.

Comment: If you're unsure the format of the date, maya may be a helpful library to check out: https://github.com/timofurrer/maya

Comment: What is the date format? Where's a minimal example? What have you tried so far? As it is, you're definitely looking to get your question closed.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have so far spent zero time with the `datetime` Python built-in class ...

It is reasonable to assume that the `date` parameter to your function already is an object of that class.  Therefore, you simply need to return the value that is produced by an appropriate call to its `strftime` method.  (The entire purpose of this function being "to conceal this 'necessary bit of business' from everyone else.)